# Length of an arc of a circle when the angle is infinitesimally small

Tags: circles, angle

The task is to express the length of an arc of a circle trapped between two radii named $r$ if the angle between them is infinitesimally small, named $d\theta$.

The solution to this problem is supposed to be:

$$l=r \cdot {d\theta}$$

but I do not understand why this would be the case.

I've provided a simple Paint sketch for more details: 
[image]

Since $d\theta$ is infinitesimally small, line $\overline{BE}$ is infinitesimally small as well, so we note that with $\overline {BE} = dx$. Since $dx$ is so small, its projection $\overline {BD}$ and circular chord $\overline{BC}$ can be approximated as: 
$$\overline{BD} \approx \overline{BC} \approx dx$$
The similar can be concluded for the radii: 
$$\overline{AB} = \overline{AC} = r$$
$$r \approx \overline{AD} \approx \overline {AE}$$

The task was to find the length of an arc limited with the chord $\overline {BC}$, that is, trapped between $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$. The solution should be $l=r \cdot {d\theta}$, but how?

Formula for deducing arc length is:
$$l=2r\pi \frac{d\theta}{360°} = r\pi \frac{d\theta}{180°}$$

The only way for this to become $l=r\cdot d\theta$ is if $\pi$ and $180°$ would somehow cancel each other out. $\pi rad$ indeed has the value of $180°$, but this $\pi$ has the meaning of length, that is $\pi \approx 3.14$, and not radians.

If there I did not specify something enough, please let me know, so I can explain myself better. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The solution $r \cos d\theta$ is wrong. It should be $r d\theta$, from the exact solution $2\sin(\frac12 d\theta)$.

Comment: @TonyK with all due respect, I highly doubt this. The solution comes from a second edition of a validated textbook and is used in every example following this one. I am aware that the solution is only an approximation, but if you have a proof to support your statement, I would highly appreciate if you could share it.

Comment: With all due respect, all you have to do is let $d\theta$ tend to zero to see that your esteemed textbook has screwed up.

Comment: @postmortes I edited the question. The solution is supposed to be $r \cdot d\theta$ , NOT $r \cdot \cos{d\theta}$

Comment: As I said...${}$

Comment: @TonyK I edited the question. The solution should be $r \cdot d\theta$ but I STILL  don't know why.

Comment: This is a problem of units. If $\mathrm d\theta$ is in radians then the length is $r\,\mathrm d\theta$. But if $\mathrm d\theta$ is in degrees, the length is $r\pi\,\cfrac{\mathrm d\theta}{180^\circ}$...

Comment: @Rahul YES! Thank you!!! Could you please post your comment above so I can choose it as the best answer?

Answer (score -1):

Consider a circle has radius $r$ units.
length of circumference is $2\pi r$ which produces total angle  $2 \pi$ radians.
unit radian angle produce arc length$= \frac{2\pi r}{2\pi} = r$ units
"$\theta$ radian (no matter how small or big it is )" angle produces arc length $= \theta r$.

#### ANOTHER WAY

Two end points of the arc is very close to each other forming an angle $dA$ in radians. For small angle $\tan dA = dA$. you can also draw a tangent at that point.

For right-angle triangle:
$$\tan dA  = dA =  \text{length of arc / radius} $$

so length of arc $= r dA$ ...